# how to horizontally center a div of 10000px (wider than full screen) in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to  horizontally center  a div of 10000px (or others wider than full screen)   in CSS?

e.g.

```
#widerdiv{
    width:10000px;
    height:100px;
    border:#009933 1px solid;
}
```

it seems "margin: 0 auto" doesn't work in this situation

Comment: Why 10000? That is an extremely large number!! And where are you trying to center it? Inside of another div? In the body tags of the HTML text?

Comment: Works the same as div with any other size. The reason you don't see a difference might be that you are unable to check it out properly.

Comment: Is there anything worse than horizontal scrolling in a browser?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes! There is. Zooming and horizontal scroll together.

Comment: Do you mean that the center of the div should be in the center of the screen? (That would mean that the left side of the div is cut off and can't be scrolled to.) Or that the screen should be horizontally scrolled to the center of the div? Those are the only cases of "horizontally center" that make sense when the content is wider than the screen.

Comment: ctrl- a few times to double check

Comment: What possible device/display has 10000px of width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add similar to

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

As ridiculous of a width as that is.. I have two solutions for you.

The margin won't work because it has nothing to align itself with so here are two possibilities.

First Solution: Use a div to wrap it. The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Yfy/) and the code below:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="widerdiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for first solution

```
#wrapper{
    width: 1000px
}
#widerdiv {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    border:#009933 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Second Solution: Define your body width. The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Yfy/1/) and the code below(which is only CSS because I would not have modified your HTML) :

```
body{
    width: 1000px
}
#widerdiv {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    border:#009933 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now, by all means necessary, you can make that width as big as you want (heaven forbid the horizontal scrolling...) but if you play with those JsFiddles, you are going to realize that you absolutely need to define a width of whatever this Div is inside of.

Last, the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/) is going to be your friend on this one. And as a quick breakdown, incase you decide to try vertical positioning, this is what happens when you use 'margin: 0 auto;' in CSS:

```
"The element is given a specified width
The left and right margins are set to auto
Without the specified width, the auto values would 
essentially have no effect, setting the left and right 
margins to 0 or else to whatever is the available space 
inside the parent element.

It should also be pointed out that auto is useful 
only for horizontal centering, and so using auto for
top and bottom margins will not center an element horizontally, 
which can be confusing for beginners."
```

The quote above is also referenced in the Almanac.